# PFQueryTableViewController two sections with two dataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I would like to have a `PFQueryTableViewController` with two sections:

- section 1: displays the `PFObjects` queried (contacts from the address book who are using the app)
- section 2: displays the objects of an array (lists of all contacts from the address book)

At the moment I'm setting the number of sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

İ'm setting the number of rows per section:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1)
    {
        return [self.contacts count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.objects count];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I try to display the content of the cells I get a crash while scrolling:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    name.text = object[@"username"];
    [cell addSubview:name];
    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        name.text = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell addSubview:name];
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.contacts objectAtIndex:20]);
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

I get the error: `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]` The reason must be because `PFObject` gets queried for every row of sections 1 and 2 and as I have more objects on sections 2, it automatically gets out of bounds and crashes while scrolling.

What is the best way to display two sections with two `dataSource`s in a `PFQueryTableViewController`? Do I have to embed a `PFQueryTableViewController` inside a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a `PFQueryTableViewController` would serve you well here. It would probably be better to use a regular `UITableViewController`, and have two queries that are combined and displayed in the table. The PFQTVC was meant to be used with one datasource.